# How can I make code more time-efficient that calculates 1's in binary representation of int?

Tags: c++

I wrote this code for a problem that asks me to calculate the number of 1's in a binary representation of an integer number, and then find the next number which has the same exact number of 1's in its binary number.

I wrote code and it seemed to work just fine until the [OJ](http://lightoj.com/volume_showproblem.php?problem=1042) gives an error:

> time limit exceeded error.

I'd like some idea about how I could avoid this error.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;
int binary(int num){
    int count=0;
    vector <int> vec;
    while(num!=0){
        int rem=num%2;
        num/=2;
        vec.push_back(rem);
    }
    reverse(vec.begin(),vec.end());
    for(int i=0;i<vec.size();i++){
        if(vec[i]==1){
            count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
int main()
{
    int looper,order=1;
    cin>>looper;
    while(looper--){
        int num;
    cin>>num;
    int x=binary(num);


    int next_num=num+1;
    while(binary(next_num)!=x){
        next_num++;
    }
    cout<<"Case "<<order<<": "<<next_num<<endl;
    order++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
int next_num=num+1;
while(binary(next_num)!=x){
    next_num++;
}
```

Is extremely inefficient. Consider your number is

```
1010101.....01111
```

Then the next bigger number with same number of `1`s is

```
1010101.....11110
```

I'll leave it to you to realize the general pattern, the point is just that you dont need a loop to convert all numbers to binary and count the `1`s. Instead you can directly construct the number in binary.

PS: `std::bitset` can come in handy when you need to get the binary representation.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to count `1's` if you're just finding next number that has same `numbers of 1's`

You just need to swap **1 & 0** from right to left for once.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

int binary(int num){
    int count=0;
    vector <int> vec;
    while(num!=0){
        int rem=num%2;
        num/=2;
        vec.push_back(rem);
    }
    reverse(vec.begin(),vec.end());
    for(int i=0;i<vec.size();i++){
        while(vec[0]!=vec[i]){
             swap(vec[0],vec[i]);
    }

    // convert binary to decimal 
    // count = decimal number
    return count;
}
int main()
{
    int looper,order=1;
    cin>>looper;
    while(looper--){
        int num;
    cin>>num;
    int x=binary(num);


    cout<<"Case "<<order<<": "<<x<<endl;
    order++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I didn't write code to convert binary to decimal, remaining is as it is.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your description. The next largest number after `6: 0110` is `9: 1001`. Seems like it requires more than a single swap.